# Simple data annotations validation not showing up in View (no red grid line)

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml

I'm using Entity Framework.

According to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx

> "With no additional code or markup changes in the application, an
>   existing MVC application will perform client side validation"

The binding is correct.

The validation doesn't filter down to the DataGrid and I get an exception on SaveChanges.

**Model**

```
private string _Sponsor;
[Required]
[StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3)]
public string Sponsor
{
    get
    {
        return _Sponsor;
    }
    set
    {
        _Sponsor = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Sponsor");
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
JobCollectionContext _context = new JobCollectionContext();

CollectionViewSource jobViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("jobViewSource")));

_context.JobCollection.Load();

jobViewSource.Source = _context.JobCollection.Local;
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Sponsor" Binding="{Binding Sponsor, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Because this is not an [`MVC`](http://www.asp.net/mvc) application. You are developing a `WPF` application.**

If you want to show the errors in a `WPF` application, you need to implement the interface `INotifyDataErrorInfo`.

I have a base class that implements the necessary logic. Just inherit from it and call `ValidateProperty("propertyName")` and it will use the `Attributes` to validate the given property.

You should do this in all setters of properties that should be validated, like you are doing it with `NotifyPropertyChanged()` to keep the UI updated.

```
public abstract class NotifyDataErrorModel : INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Maps properties to their error sets
    /// </summary>
    protected Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> errors;
    /// <summary>
    /// maps a property to a list of properties 
    /// the list of properties will get the ValidationErrors of the property
    /// </summary>
    protected NotifyDataErrorModel()
    {
        errors = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
        var properties = getProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            errors.Add(property, new HashSet<string>());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> getProperties()
    {
        var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
        properties.Remove("HasErrors"); //remove the HasErrors property, because it is part of the interface INotifyDataErrorInfo and not of the actual model
        return properties;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="property">the property to validate</param>
    public virtual void ValidateProperty(string property)
    {
        //clear the errors on the matched property
        errors[property].Clear();

        var type = this.GetType();
        //the entity framework proxies sometimes dont inherit the attributes of the properties
        //so if it is a entity framework proxy object, get the base class (which is the actual model class) instead
        if (type.FullName.Contains("System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies"))
        {
            type = type.BaseType;
        }
        var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(property);
        var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(this);
        var validationAttributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<ValidationAttribute>();
        foreach (var validationAttribute in validationAttributes)
        {
            if (!validationAttribute.IsValid(propertyValue))
            {
                errors[property].Add(validationAttribute.FormatErrorMessage(string.Empty));
            }
        }
        raiseErrorsChanged(property);
    }

    public virtual void ValidateAllProperties()
    {
        var properties = getProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties) ValidateProperty(property);
    }

    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
    {
        //if the propertyname is not valid, return an empty IEnumerable
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)) return new List<string>();

        return errors[propertyName];
    }

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get { return errors.Any((propertyErrors) => propertyErrors.Value.Count > 0); }
    }

    private void raiseErrorsChanged(string property)
    {
        if (ErrorsChanged != null)
        {
            var eventArgs = new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(property);
            ErrorsChanged(this, eventArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would one use custom attributes with the above? i.e. property1 != property2

Comment: I've tried CompareAttribute [CompareAttribute("Property",ErrorMessage = "ERROR")] however the code above doesn't seem to be compatible with it.

Comment: I dont see why it shouldnt be. Can you post the error message?

Comment: NullReferenceException on !validationAttribute.IsValid(propertyValue)

Comment: Do you know which value is null? propertyValue?

Comment: No I think the IsValid method is returning null perhaps because it matches?

Comment: IsValid always returns a boolean. So that shouldnt be the problem. But its difficult to pinpoint mistakes here. You can create a new question for it, there  you can post more code (your class that contains CompareAttribute for example) and the exact error message. You can also post a link to the question here, then I'll have a look at it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347290/notifydataerrormodel-cross-property-validation-with-entity-framework

Comment: @Domysee, I am using very similar code.  In my method similar to raiseErrorsChanged(),  ErrorsChanged is always null for me.  What line of code in your example does ErrorsChanged become not null?  Thanks.